# The return of the database data in json

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with the return of the database data in json here is my code:

models:

```
class Savedrequest(models.Model):
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
data1 = JSONField()
data2 = JSONField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.data1, self.data2, self.date
```

view:

```
def affiche(request): 
queryset= Savedrequest.objects.all()
datajson= list(queryset)

context = {
    "object_list":datajson,
           }


return render(request,"affiche.html" ,context)
```

html:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {{obj.date}}
    <textarea id="txth" class='txtarea' style="display:;" >{{obj.data1.result}}</textarea>
    <textarea id="txtv" class='txtarea' style="display:;" >{{obj.data2.result}}</textarea>
{% endfor %}
```

The return json I would like is:

```
[{u'luns': [{u'host_cluster_id': 0, u'volume_id': 1012, u'clustered': False, u'host_id': 1006, u'id': 1, u'lun': 1}, {u'host_cluster_id': 0, u'volume_id': 1016, u'clustered': False, u'host_id': 1006, u'id': 2, u'lun': 2}]'
```

Comment: Please format your question well so it won't hurt reader's eyes

Comment: have you tried to use a filter (stringformat): `{{ obj.data1|stringformat:"s" }}`?

Comment: You're rendering a template - where's it supposed to be generating the json?